# Implementing Toro Required htaccess Rewrite on Windows Server IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, mod-rewrite

I'm installing [ToroPHP](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP) (PHP routing class) on my server.  However, it happens to be my first windows server, I'm trying to learn it.

Here is the required ModRewrite code as if it was an Apache server for Toro:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have read through these two articles/questions, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it isn't working.  I'm hoping somebody can walk through each part of the "windows IIS ported version" of this...

Here's what I'm trying, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="toro" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$ /index.php/$1" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="{UrlEncode:{R:1}} !^(index\.php)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="^(.*)$ /index.php/{UrlEncode:{R:1}}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

[URL ReWrite for Windows Server (IIS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/333891/url-rewrite-for-windows-server-iis)
and
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Toro as well and this work for me, but not the root "/".
Found this  on IIS.net:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To make the root work, you will need to make a modification into the Toro.php file, on line 11, replace the line:

```
$path_info = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : $path_info);
```

by

```
$path_info = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : ((isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) and $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] !== "/index.php") ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : $path_info);
```

For some reason IIS return the `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` as equal as `/index.php` instead of `/`.

Comment: What do you mean not the root "/" ?

Comment: I can not make the homeHandler work on that example     `Toro::serve(array(  
        "/" => "homeHandler",  
        "/the-company" => "companyHandler"  
    ));`

Comment: So what happens when somebody visits your root site "www.domain.com" ?  If the handler doesn't get called, you just see a blank page or something? haha.

Comment: It will server the 404 ToroHook that I setup.          ToroHook::add("404", function() { include '404.html'; });

Comment: Does your updated answer fix this behavior?

Comment: Nope, I just found a cleaner version from who is supported by a source.

Comment: Hmmm I also just found this one: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/url-rewrite-removing-index-php-on-iis-7  - might give it a shot as well.

Comment: I found a solution to resolve this root problem, it's coming form IIS way to send $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']. I submitted a pull request to Toro for they next update.

Comment: You're the man!  I'll give it a shot, I'll report back if it works, makes sense though.